# Android アプリでトーストの処理方法について

Tags: java, android

Android Studio でアプリを製作しているのですが、下段のようなコードを組んで一旦プログラム処理を止めている間にトーストで ”処理停止中” と表示し (処理が止まっている間はずっと表示したまま)、停止時間が終わったらトーストを ”処理停止解除” に変えて表示し数秒で消えるようなトーストの動作をさせたいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？

通常のトーストの使用方法では数秒表示して消えてしまうのどうすればよいか悩んでおります。
アドバイス頂きたいです。

ThreadSample.java

```
class ThreadSample extends Thread {
    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000L); // 10秒(10000ms)間、スレッドを停止させる
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

    }
}
```

ThreadExecutor.java

```
class ThreadExecutor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new ThreadSample();
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

無理やり表示させ続けるなら可能かもしれませんが、toastを表示させ続けるのは現実的ではありません。
例えば同じような質問がされています。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long

アプリがフォアグラウンドにある時ユーザーに通知し続けたい場合は、snackbarsの仕様を検討してください。
https://material.io/components/snackbars/android

アプリがバックグラウンドへ遷移しても通知が必要な場合は、ステータスバーでの通知を検討してください。
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: 現実的ではないのならprogress barなら可能でしょうか？progress barでも構いませんので、宜しければ上記コードでprogress barを使用した場合どのようなコードになるかアドバイス頂けないでしょうか？PROGRESS dialogクラスは使用したことがなく、いまいち使い方が解っておりませんのでお手数ですが何とか宜しくお願いいたします。